# How to solve the leaks in the following code? ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I getting leak here which is written in the appDelegate.m

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getSalutationList
{
    NSMutableArray *list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"Dr."];
    [list addObject:@"Mr."];
    [list addObject:@"Mrs."];
    [list addObject:@"Miss."];
    [list addObject:@"Ms."];
    return list;    //return [list autorelease]; if i keep this  i am getting exception.
}
```

How to release the list and also i need the content which I am calling from view controller.

Comment: How do you use the return value of `-getSalutationList`?

Comment: listformAppdelegate= [appDelegate getSalutaionList]; and this list is used to display the contents in View Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a reported leak because the memory management guidelines say that you're supposed to be returning an autoreleased object.  In addition, you shouldn't be prefixing your method name with "get" unless you're planning on providing data via an out parameter.

So your method should be:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) salutationList {
    NSMutableArray *list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"Dr."];
    [list addObject:@"Mr."];
    [list addObject:@"Mrs."];
    [list addObject:@"Miss."];
    [list addObject:@"Ms."];
    return [list autorelease];
}
```

If you're getting an exception by returning `[list autorelease]`, then your problem lies elsewhere (perhaps you're releasing the array somewhere else when you shouldn't be?).

Comment: It is declared locally and not released any where. Is it possible to release the main list and return the temperory list